# Dense Subset Multiple Choice Question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Which of the following statements are true?

a. If $A$ is a dense subset of a topological space $X$, then $X \setminus A$ is nowhere dense in $X$.

b. If $A$ is a nowhere dense subset of a topological space $X$, then $X \setminus A$ is
dense in $X$.

c. The set $\Bbb R$, identified with the x-axis in $\Bbb R^2$, is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

I have tried to find out examples but could not succeed. Please Help.

Comment: If $A$ is a subspace of toplolgical space $X$, then what do you think $X \cap A$ is? It is A ifself, hence if A is dense in $X$ then $X \cap A$ is also dense in $X$ and if $A$ is nowhere dense then $X\cap A$ is also nowhere dense in $X$. You are only left with option C. First study some basics, then ask questions.

Comment: that was not  X∩A ,it was X-A(X difference A). i think you have mistaken somewhere.so edit the question properly

Comment: poton, you wrote XnA, how is anbody supposed to figure out it is not $X \cap A$, and it is $A^c$. Post the questions correctly. And learn some latex, it's not that difficult. So edit your questions yourself, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) Think about $\Bbb Q$.

(b) This is true; if you understand the definitions of *dense* and *nowhere dense*, the proof is trivial.

(c) This also is true, and if you understand the definition of *nowhere dense*, the proof is trivial.

These are pretty small hints, because this problem really is extremely easy; if you’re really having trouble with it, you should probably talk to your instructor.

Comment: Regarding a: is it not true in general that if a set $A$ is dense in $X$ then $A^c$ is also dense in $X$?

Comment: @Matt: Absolutely not! What if $A=X$?

Comment: Oops. Do you also have a counter example if the subset is proper? (I have an excuse: I'm allowed to say non-sense since I got food poisoning 2 days ago and I'm still sick)

Comment: Sure: $X=\Bbb R$, $A=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Or $A=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$.